# Stateful EJBs in web application?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, stateful

I never used stateful EJBs. 
I understand that a stateful EJB can be useful with a java client.

But i wonder: in which case to use them on a web application?  And how?
Should we put these stateful beans in Session (because of stateless http)?

Is it a good practice? 
(without debating too much about stateful vs stateless)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Funny enough, it's a 2nd question on SFSB and web app for the day, while this topic is usually not that common.

> in which case to use them on a web
>   application?

The traditional example of SFSB and web app is the shopping cart. But at the same time, you can do the same with the `HttpSession`.

Ideally, **if the state relates to the business logic** and not the presentation logic, it should go in a SFSB. But in practice, people usually advocates against SFSB (because of the complexity it introduces) unless they provide something you can not do easily with the `HttpSession`. Most of the time, you can tweak the design to store the information in the `HttpSession` or the database and pass it around, without the need to have SFSB. But it's ultimately a **question of design purity**.

> And how? Should we put these stateful
>   beans in Session (because of stateless
>   http)?

The EJB model is a richer model than the `HttpSession`, because EJB are transactional components, and there are explicit callbacks for the passivation and activation of SFSB. This comes with an **increased complexity** about how to use SFSB correctly, notably (1) exception handling and (2) concurrency and (2) removal and time-out of SFSB. See my answers here for more details:

- [Java: Tracking a user login session - Session EJBs vs HTTPSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808773/java-tracking-a-user-login-session-session-ejbs-vs-httpsession/2811086#2811086)
- [Correct usage of Stateful Beans with Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935178/correct-usage-of-stateful-beans-with-servlets/1935476#1935476)

If you want to use them, you will need first to look up the SFSB to get a reference to one fresh remote instance. Then you will need to store this reference somewhere in a way to reuse it across requests. This *somewhere* is usually the `HttpSession`, which means that even if you use SFSB, you can't get rid of it completely.

With EJB2, the remote reference -- called a *handle* -- could be serialized to be reused later. It was then possible to store if for instance in database, even though I've never seen that. I don't know if it's still possible with EJB3.

> Is it a good practice?

As I said already, **people usually advice against it** unless you know exactly why you would use them rather than the `HttpSession` and only if you have a good command of the EJB model. (SFSB could be justified for instance if the business service is accessible through a web front-end and a desktop client) Lots of other frameworks *don't* have something similar as SFSB and people still manage to create great apps with them.

*PS: I've used SFSB in a web app, and it can indeed be a trickier to use than the `HttpSession`, but it ultimately worked.*

Comment: One extra reason for a SFSB is to take advantage of the `extended persistence context` in JPA. This is an advanced subject and should be used moderately, but if you need it, it's definitely a reason to go for a SFSB.