# Unsynchronized objects in a synchronized class

Tags: java, synchronization, ejb

Suppose I have a stateless session bean which is synchronized by the app server and I declare a StringBuilder as a class member(non-static). Is it also synchronized? Or do I have to synchonize myself?

Comment: It is not synchronized. There's no magic there. However, if you happen to access it only through methods which are synchronized themselves, it may not matter.

Comment: I would doubt your claim that an SLSB is synchronized by the container. The point of being stateless is that it *doesn't* need synchronization.

Comment: `Variables` are not synchronised. Access to them via `functions/blocks` can be synchronized, as far as i know :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935178/correct-usage-of-stateful-beans-with-servlets/1935476#1935476 post says that an SLSB is synchronized by the app server.

Comment: SLSB beans are not synchronized in terms of Java. Just the container doesn't allow two clients to use the same instance simultaneously.