# Stateful session bean and concurrent access

Tags: java, ejb

i need some explanation about stateful session bean and concurrent access. is multi-threaded access to a stateful session bean instance is allowed?

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1935476/778118) seems relevant.

Comment: @BheshGurung - I believe that's true for `EJB 3.1` but not `EJB 3.0`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1935476/778118).

Comment: with ejb 3.1 : clients are allowed to make concurrent calls to a stateful session object and the container is 
required to serialize such concurrent requests. Note that the container never permits multi-threaded 
access to the actual stateful session bean instance. so, if a method of stateful bean is executed and a second call to the same method comes, this method have to wait until the first call is processed. right?

Comment: @Moam Yes, that's right.